# Не меняется директория

Tags: c++

Проблема: Когда вывожу директорию в которой нахожусь как в 1-ом примере, то всё работает отлично.

А когда вывожу как во 2-ом, то во втором выводе директория остаётся той же. (Что и до cd ..)

```
// Первый пример
system("pwd");
system("cd .. && pwd");

// Второй пример
system("pwd");
system("cd ..");
system("pwd");
```

Comment: Само собой. Сессия закрывается, все возвращается на круги своя - каталог в том числе...

Comment: @Harry Как нибудь это можно исправить? (Не используя пример 1)

Comment: Воспользоваться нормальными функциями, типа [`chdir`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/chdir)

Comment: Она есть в стандартной библеотеке C++?

Comment: Нет, это POSIX, но я еще не видел компилятора, где ее нет :) Там есть, конечно, тонкости, зависящие от ОС - у вас для Linux?

Comment: Да Linux, но я также пишу и под виндовс иногда

Comment: @lakvak, почитайте [man execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) и ссылочки оттуда